# Can I use my adoptable storage chip after a factory reset

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, factory-reset, adoptable-storage

I need to do a factory reset of my android marshmallow phone, but I use adoptable storage. Will I be able to use the adoptable storage chip with the apps installed after I do a factory reset?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will be wiped during the reset. If you remove it and then factory reset, it will remain encrypted to the "previous" system and will not be usable even in the same device with out formating and adopting again.