# Unable to recover SD card used as internal memory after factory reset

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, encryption, adoptable-storage

I have Motorolla G3 Android 6.0 phone. I am using 32 gb SD card as internal storage.
After removing my 32gb card I did factory reset, now after factory reset my device doesn't recognize my SD card its saying to format it, however I have lots of stuff which I don't want to delete.
Is there any tool / program which I can use to recover the data or access my photos. Is it necessary to format my SD card ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my adoptable storage chip after a factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151675/can-i-use-my-adoptable-storage-chip-after-a-factory-reset)

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Yes.

**Details:** By adopting your SD card as internal storage, it was encrypted. The encryption key was stored on the device itself – and thus deleted when you performed the [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). For that reason, the device can no longer decrypt it and read the data stored there.

So unfortunately, there is no way to recover the data you had stored on the card, as the key is lost. The only ones able to perform that miracle would be forensics – and they would ask a sum you'll unlikely be willing to pay (if you're very lucky, it would only be 4 digits befoe the dot, with the unit being US$ or €).

For more details on [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage) and how it works, please take a look at our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](/tags/adoptable-storage/info).